# How do I determine the maximum height in pixels of a given font?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I need to measure or somehow determine the maximum height for a given font.

I also need to determine where the baseline of the font is.

The `Graphics.MeasureString` function seems to only determine the bounding box of a particular string (which is useful, but not what I need right now).

Specifically, I'm looking for ONLY the vertical size of the font in pixels.  However, it needs to vertically accommodate all possible strings.

Is this something that is possible to programatically determine?

Comment: As in `Font.Height`? I'm not sure if that's what you want, though. You could try measuring a string made up of all ASCII characters if need be...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#/GDI+:". That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.height.aspx) property of your font, which is "the line spacing, in pixels, of this font". The position of the baseline (above the top of the next line of text) is given by the [GetCellDescent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.getcelldescent.aspx) method of the font family, but it is in "design units", which has to be converted to pixels ([here is how](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/dotnet.gui/2949686.1.aspx)). There is an [interesting article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx) on MSDN about obtaining font metrics.